# Troubles while installing any Linux OS on Asus TUF FX504

Tags: linux, system-installation, laptop, asus

Tried to install Ubuntu, Antergos and Kali linux KDE on a new laptop [Asus TUF FX504](https://www.userbenchmark.com/System/Asus-TUF-GAMING-FX504GM-FX80GM/93476). Before I did it I

- disabled Fast & Secure boot
- set the SATA Mode Selection to AHCI
- disabled legacy USB Support (a friend of mine had troubles
  during Ubuntu installation because of it)

After that installation started. After loading, when showing the  language menu:

- Ubuntu installation froze: did not respond for minutes, until a hard reset
- Antergos went in Fallback Mode, and in
- Kali Linux didn't find the files of the OS.

**[Update]**

Doing this command:

```
certutil -hashfile kali-linux-kde-2018.4-amd64.iso
```

i obtained this output with the hash:

```
SHA1 hash di kali-linux-kde-2018.4-amd64.iso:
a8a86359265f898656d747005fab39d7a45a529d
```

What can I do next?

Comment: Did you check the md5sum or sha256sum of the downloaded iso files before copying them to the media used for install?

Comment: Your adding more data into the question is ideal. All the information needed to understand a problem should be in the Question. Using Comments for you to add more info is contraindicated, because Comments pile up quickly and get hidden. Please keep doing what you're doing!

Comment: There are multiple checksum apps for use with Windows 10. See https://www.nextofwindows.com/5-ways-to-generate-and-verify-md5-sha-checksum-of-any-file-in-windows-10 and https://www.maketecheasier.com/verify-md5-sha-1-sha-256-checksum-windows10/

Comment: @Stecco I approved your suggested edit but approvals wouldn't be necessary if you merge your two accounts. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Answer (score 2):

The issue is related to acpi and video drivers. You can workaround it by adding `acpi_osi=Linux` and `nouveou.modeset=0` kernel parameters in the grub entry during installation and initial starts.

I followed [this guide](https://dk4g.blogspot.com/2018/12/installing-linux-on-asus-tuf-fx504-ge.html) for drivers setup in Ubuntu 18.04. I recommend to use nvidia-drivers-4.18 instead of 4.15 version in step 6 as I experimented freezes during next boots. After switching to 4.18 everything works fine.

Just in case... I did the installation using `acpi=off` before finding that guide.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to install ubuntu in that model.
First of all the boot usb I was using had problems, try to use a new usb to create the boot device.
Next, the screen is frozen because of missing drivers of the video card. You can change the system to use the integrated Intel video card or install the drivers to use the Nvidia Card.
You can use the next post to install the nvidia drivers and solve the problem.

[How to install the NVIDIA drivers on Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-nvidia-drivers-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux)

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Ubuntu 19.04 version solves most of the acpi and video driver issues. But one problem of wifi driver being unassigned still persisted which has prompted me to do hwe kernel updation.

Hopefully, 20.04 Ubuntu to be released in 4 months will have the smoothest driver support for Asus TUF FX505

Answer (score 0):

You should install nvidia 450 drivers from ppa for ubuntu

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-450
$ shutdown -r now
```

Then you can use eGPU with

```
__NV_PRIME_RENDER_OFFLOAD=1 __GLX_VENDOR_LIBRARY_NAME=nvidia COMMAND_YOU_WANT
```

Look at this : http://doc.kubuntu-fr.org/asus-a17-tuf766iu